# How do I use the find command to effectively recurse when the pattern contains a wildcard?

Tags: command-line, find

I was under the impression that the following command will search for, and list all Java files starting from the current directory and recursing down.

However, if I have a Java file in the root of my home directory, it lists that one, and then stops.

Is find supposed to stop at the first match, even with a wildcard?  I guess I have a misconception about the usage.  Thanks for any enlightenment.

```
find . -name *.java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard pattern `*.java` is expanded by your shell before it is passed to the `find` command. If you have a single file `foo.java` in the current directory, then the shell executes the command `find . -name foo.java`. If you have two files `bar.java` and `foo.java`, the command `find . -name bar.java foo.java` is executed and `find` complains of a syntax error. If there is no matching file in the current directory, then the shell leaves the pattern unexpanded, so `find . -name *.java` is executed as you desire.

To tell the shell not to expand the pattern, so that it is always passed as-is to `find`, quote it:

```
find . -name '*.java'
find . -name "*.java"
find . -name \*.java
```

Comment: Splendid!  Thanks.   Shall "accept" in 3 minute.